# What is the best way for AsyncTask to notify parent Activity about completion?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity

```
public class ListingFoundBeaconService 
                    extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    public ListingFoundBeaconService(Context contextGiven, 
                                     JSONObject jsonParams) {
        this.contextGiven = contextGiven;
        this.jsonParams = jsonParams;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(contextGiven);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading list of active Beacons..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
        Log.d("onPreExecute","onPreExecute worked" );
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {}

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {   
        // Two activities will need this thread so I have 
        // kept this as a separate class. Here I want to send a
        // boolean value to the parent activity to show that 
        // the task has completed or not.
    }
```

Can I trigger a notification or complete event listener in `onPostExecute()` function so that the parent class which started this class(`ListingFoundBeaconService`) is notified? What is the standard way of doing it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Best way is to call delegate. In your `AsyncTask` class make a constructor and have a delegate

Delegate interface:

```
public interface TaskDelegate {
    public void taskCompletionResult(String result);
}
```

now in `AsyncTask`:

```
private TaskDelegate delegate;

public ListingFoundBeaconService(Context contextGiven, 
                                 JSONObject jsonParams,
                                 TaskDelegate delegate) {
    this.contextGiven = contextGiven;
    this.jsonParams = jsonParams;
    this.delegate = delegate;
}
```

on `postExecute`:

```
delegate.taskCompletionResult(result/msg/json);
```

In your main class implement `TaskDelegate` and implemented a method which is called when the task completed.

Comment: i found this http://256design.com/blog/asynctask-in-android-and-oncompletelistener/ any comments about using this ??

Comment: I see your link it is android specific and we are concentrating on java native code and specially link code put burden of anonymous inner class other than that link concept will work, but you can set two functions failure and success in your delegate too.
Enjoy

Comment: taskDelegateResult ?? it should be taskCompletionResult

Comment: in my main class, i am passing reference like this                                                   TaskDelegateReference = this;                            ListingFoundBeaconService Lfb_object = new ListingFoundBeaconService(findBeaconContext,jsonData,TaskDelegateReference);

Comment: This can't be the best way. What happen if the Activity is recreated? The current (recreated) activity never receives the callback.

Comment: FYI, the link that Muhammad posted to 256design.com is broken. An updated link is http://soberstadt.github.io/asynctask-in-android-and-oncompletelistener/

Comment: Beautiful solution. Would have come really in handy to also have built-in delegates in Java!

Answer (score 0):

Make the ListingFoundBeaconService class abstract and then override onPostExecute in the calling class.