# Using delegates for AsyncTask

Tags: android, delegates

I'm having trouble implementing a delegate in my android app.

In my GetData class I have nested asynctask, and I need to notify my main activity when all the work has actually finished.

I came up with this answer from Mohd Mufiz
[What is the best way for AsyncTask to notify parent Activity about completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416644/what-is-the-best-way-for-asynctask-to-notify-parent-activity-about-completion)

But I always get stuck at the same point:
in my GetData class I call a constructor with the delegate as only argument:

```
public class GetData {

    private TaskDelegate delegate;

    public GetData(TaskDelegate delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }
...
}
```

In my main activity I don't know what I have to pass to get it working:

```
 GetData getData = new GetData(**???**);
```

Comment: `**??**` = `new TaskDelegate () { /*inline implementation goes here*/ }` or `anyTaskDelegateInstanceThatYouHave`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going from the question you linked to, that defined TaskDelegate as :

```
public interface TaskDelegate {
    public void taskCompletionResult(String result);
}
```

You can pass GetData any instance of a class that implements TaskDelegate - but typically, that would be the object that creates it - ie. your main activity (and so, therefore, it would also implement "void taskCompletionResult(String result);").  That then means you can pass "this" to GetData's constructor, so :

```
public class MyMainActivity implements TaskDelegate {

    public void someMethod() {
        GetData getData = new GetData(this);
    }

    public void taskCompletionResult(String result) {
        // do stuff
    }
 }
```