# Is it possible to retain Asynctask variables after the task is finished?

Tags: java, android

I have several fairly large csv files that I wish to import and store as variables thus, I am using an asyncTask to open and store all the data. (I know this can be done using a database but I want it functional offline that is why I have chosen this path.)

I figured that the local variables and it's data is removed when the task is finished so I tried to store the variables 'globally' (not sure about the Java terminology but basically the variables can be accessed by all functions within that class). Right now, the data is being stored in a 2d array and whilst I'm within *doInBackground* function (of the asyncTask) I can print the values in the arrays just fine, however, once the task is finished I can no longer access it. No error messages come up the app just crashes.

Code:

public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

```
String[][] types = new String[19][2];
String[][] moves = new String[619][9];
String[][] dex = new String[785][6];

private class LoadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {

            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("types.csv")));
            List<String[]> list = reader.readAll();
            types = list.toArray(types);

            CSVReader reader_moves = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("moves.csv")));
            List<String[]> list_moves = reader_moves.readAll();
            moves = list_moves.toArray(moves);

            CSVReader reader_pokedex = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("dex.csv")));
            List<String[]> list_dex = reader_pokedex.readAll();
            dex = list_dex.toArray(dex);

            for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++ )
                    Log.w("app", types[i][j]);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++ )
                    Log.w("app", dex[i][j]);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Log.w("app", "Files Loaded" );

    }

}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    findViewById(R.id.my_button).setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
    b.setClickable(false);

    EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_edit);

    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(input.getWindowToken(), 0);


    new LoadFilesTask().execute();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++ )
            Log.w("app", moves[i][j]);
    }       
}
```

}

Comment: no help without code

Comment: See the logs when the app crashes.

Comment: please show some code, and if Your app crashs, You will get a log error report for sure..

Comment: You want to use aynsc data after `AsyncTask` is finished?

Comment: [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) might be interesting for you.

Comment: @JeanYang: essentially yes. that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You can read the question and the answer of
[What is the best way for AsyncTask to notify parent Activity about completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416644/what-is-the-best-way-for-asynctask-to-notify-parent-activity-about-completion)

You can use a delegate as a callback function.

## Step 1 : "Callback Function"

Create an interface in `LoadFilesTask`,

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
    void processFinish(String[][] types, String[][] moves, String[][] dex);
}
public AsyncResponse delegate = null;
```

and create a public constructor to force whoever wants to use `LoadFilesTask` pass `processFinish` to it.

```
//constructer
public LoadFilesTask(AsyncResponse delegate){
    this.delegate = delegate;
}
```

finally, call the delegate on `onPostExecute` (remember to declare three String arrays as global variables in `LoadFilesTask`, and pass them as params to `delegate.processFinish`)

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(...) {
    delegate.processFinish(types, moves, dex);
```

## Step 2 : Implement Your Callback Function

Your activity, which is running on UI thread:

Variables:

```
String[][] types = new String[19][2];
String[][] moves = new String[619][9];
String[][] dex = new String[785][6];
```

implements `LoadFilesTask.AsyncResponse`

```
public class YOUACTIVITY OR FRAGMENT extends ... implements LoadFilesTask.AsyncResponse, View.OnClickListener{

@Override
public void processFinish(String[][] types, String[][] moves, String[][] dex) {

    this.types =types;
    this.moves = moves;
    this.dex = dex;

    //Do whatever you want to do in Callback function
    Toast.makeText(context, "Read File Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

finally, let's execute new Task:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

//whatever

    new LoadFilesTask(this).execute();

//whatever 


}
```

Comment: For the onPostExecute section, the super.onPostExecute(...); line is giving a compile error. I've done everything else you suggested.

Comment: error:illegal expression. 
error: ';' expected.

In android studio is has the things within the parenthesis underlined in red i.e. the '...'

Comment: I looked at a few other examples which didn't have that line so I took it out and it seems to work now. Thanks for your help