# Zxing Scanner stuck after running once?

Tags: java, android, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I am making QR scanner based android application that gets the data from QR code and send to server to check the data, but my scanner stuck after scanning an invalid QR code

here's my code

**Qrresult.java**

```
 public class qrresult extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

    private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
    private FocusHandler focusHandler;
    public ImageButton back;

public void backbut() {
    back = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bckbut);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //onBackPressed();
            Intent back = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),mainmenu.class);
            startActivity(back);
        }
    });
     }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_qrresult);
        RelativeLayout zscanner = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.zxscan);
        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);   // Programmatically initialize the scanner view

        focusHandler = new FocusHandler(new Handler(), mScannerView);
        zscanner.addView(mScannerView);
        backbut();

    }

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mScannerView.setResultHandler(this); // Register ourselves as a handler for scan results.
    mScannerView.setAutoFocus(false);
    mScannerView.startCamera();
    focusHandler.start();

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mScannerView.stopCamera();
    focusHandler.stop(); //Stop camera on pause
}
@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    mScannerView.stopCamera();
}
@Override
public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
        // Do something with the result here
        String qrdata= rawResult.getText();
        qrresultWorker qrresultWorker= new qrresultWorker(this);
        qrresultWorker.execute(qrdata);
        //mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);

        // If you would like to resume scanning, call this method below:
        //mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
    }
}
```

**QrresultWorker.java**

```
 public class qrresultWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {



private Context context;
private AlertDialog alertDialog;
private ProgressDialog Asycdialog;
qrresultWorker(Context ctx) {
    context = ctx;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {



   String login_url = "http://10.0.2.2/projects/dbcon1/qrresult.php";


        try {

            //Used for Sending data to Database

            String qrdata = params[0];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            //httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(100000);
            //httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(100000);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("qrdata", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(qrdata, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            //Used for Getting data from Database
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
            String result = ""; //initializing with empty string
            String line = "";  //initializing with empty string
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    //progress dialog
    //Asycdialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    //Asycdialog.setMessage("Scanning...");
    //Asycdialog.show();

    //alertdialog
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                    //Intent go = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),qrresult.class);
                    //context.startActivity(go);
                dialog.dismiss();

                }
           });
    alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Scan Status");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    //Asycdialog.dismiss();

    /*String name = null;
    int balance = 0;
    String qrcode=null;
    JSONObject jsonResponse = null;
    try {
        jsonResponse = new JSONObject(result);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
*/
    if (result.equals("success")){

        Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),sendmoney.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);

    }
    else {

        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),"Coundn't scan the QR code",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //alertDialog.setMessage("Scanning Failed,Invalid Qrcode, please retry");
        //alertDialog.show();

    }


}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put condition that it scans only QR code  below code scans only QR code

just add below line in `gradle` and  use below code

```
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'
```

use below code to scan Qr code

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
  integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
  integrator.setPrompt("Scan a barcode");
  integrator.setCameraId(0);  // Use a specific camera of the device
  integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
  integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);
  integrator.initiateScan();
```

for more reference [CLICK HERE](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/example/zxing/MainActivity.java)

Comment: should i replace the zxingscanner code with this one ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing a call to `resumeCameraPreview(ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler resultHandler)` on your `ZXingScannerView` once you have finished processing the scanned data. To do this, you need to notify your Activity to call that method on the scanner view in the `onPostExecute` method of your AsyncTask. Since you've implemented the AsyncTask in a separate class, you're going to have to implement some kind of callback mechanism similar to something like this: [What is the best way for AsyncTask to notify parent Activity about completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416644/what-is-the-best-way-for-asynctask-to-notify-parent-activity-about-completion).

Comment: thanks for the info :) , i called "resumeCameraPreview(ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler resultHandler)" both , qrresult nd qrressultworker, but the problem comes that it scans 3 to 4 time and open 3 to 4 activities if qrresult is true